# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB when trying to join different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB` when trying to use `JOIN` statements to selection values from multiple tables. The following is my Oracle SQL code:

```
SELECT
    MAX(questions.id),
    MAX(questions.question),
    MAX(questions.author),
    MAX(questions.datetime),
    MAX(answers.answer),
    MAX(answers.usr),
    MAX(answers.ansdatetime)
FROM
    questions
LEFT JOIN
    answers ON
        questions.id = answers.question
LEFT JOIN
    questions_tags ON
        questions.id = questions_tags.question_id
WHERE
    questions_tags.tag_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY
    questions.id, answers.id
ORDER BY
    questions.datetime DESC
```

The following is the table structure for the three tables:

`questions`:

```
id int not null,
question varchar(999),
details varchar(1000) not null,
author int not null,
datetime varchar(999)
```

`answers`

```
id int not null, primary key(id), 
question int not null, 
answer blob not null, 
usr int not null, 
ansdatetime int not null
```

`questions_tags`

```
id INT NOT NULL,
question_id INT NOT NULL,
tag_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: My guess would be that MAX is not defined for BLOB values, so `MAX(answers.answer)` is failing. You probably actually want a sub-query rather than separately taking the MAX of each column anyway. Or just put all the selected columns in the GROUP BY rather than just the IDs.

Comment: `answers.answer` is a `blob`.  You can't do a `MAX` on a `blob`.  But it seems unlikely that you want to do a `MAX` on each individual column.  That would generally combine data together for multiple rows.  Do you really want to get the most recent answer for a particular question?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, I need to get the most recent answer for the question that's returned, if an answer exists.

Comment: @IMSoP I tried the following but still get the same error: http://pastebin.com/EbB2cf8J

Comment: DemCodeLines, I told you not to actually use that query :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments have said, this doesn't work because you can't do `max` on a `blob` column. However, you can rewrite this query to not use aggregates:

```
with a as (
    select
        *, -- might need to enumerate columns
        row_number() over (partition by question order by ansdatetime desc) as rn
    from
        answers
)
select
    q.id,
    q.question,
    q.author,
    q.datetime,
    a.answer,
    a.usr,
    a.ansdatetime
from
    questions q
        left join
    a
        on q.id = a.question and rn = 1 -- assuming you're only looking for latest answer per q
where
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            questions_tags t
        where
            q.id = t.question_id and
            t.tag_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    )
order by
    q.datetime desc
```

Comment: Gah. I wrote that monstrosity he posted in the question, more of a joke than a serious suggestion. In MySQL, the engine simply takes the first row for those columns, you can have columns in the select that are not in the group by. I worked out the initial query based on what I know (MySQL), then jokingly suggested the MAX thing when it didn't work in Oracle. Now, seeing the convoluted crap you have to do... I actually like something about MySQL now. Huh. +1 for the answer, I'd make it +2 for having the patience to deal with Oracle if I could.

Comment: @Chris Actually, MySQL does *not* take the first row for those columns, it takes *any row it likes in each group*: ["The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html). In PostgreSQL (possibly Oracle too, I don't know), you can define a `FIRST()` aggregate function and use an embedded ORDER BY (`SELECT FIRST(x ORDER BY y) ...`) so that you *are* guaranteed the first of each group. This is a good example of MySQL putting convenience before robustness.

Comment: @IMSoP Fair enough. As for whether it is a bad thing... meh. You can still use aggregate functions in MySQL too (or enable "FULL GROUP BY"), so if it matters what row the columns come from, you can specify. Seems to me that MySQL gets the best of both worlds on that one.

Comment: @Chris I think the best of both worlds would be to default to strict behaviour but allow turning it off (perhaps on a query-by-query basis) rather than just allowing SQL which someone might write by mistake and not realise the implications.